# How to handle external and internal events in blackberry (converted j2me code - jar to cod)

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I developed the game in j2me and I converted jar to cod. It's working fine in blackberry device. But `hideNotify()` method is working, so I not able to handle redkey, callevents etc.

Inside the game play, I placed background sound, when I pressed redkey, it goes to home screen but application not closed and background sound runs continuously.

How to handle events in blackberry using j2me code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle BB events, you'll have to `import` `net.rim...` libraries instead of `javax.microedition...`, which means you'll have to write event handling again. J2ME event handlers are different from BB's and BB does not recognize them. So you can run a jar file in a BB but you can not have the complete functionality.

Comment: i need to add bb plugin or i just add blackberry.jar in build path ? any sample link ?

Comment: There's a BB plugin for [eclipse](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) which you'll use for development